# How to encrypt boot partition in CentOS 7 kickstart?

Tags: partition, centos7, encryption, kickstart

I have a kickstart file for CentOS 7 Minimal. I would like to add encryption only to my /boot partition. but when I added the following line in the kickstart file, the complete installation fails. The kickstart encrypt line is

```
part /boot --encrypted --passphrase=pass1 --fstype="ext4" --size=500
```

without the `--encrypted --passphrase=pass1` option, kickstart run the installation properly.

when I tried installing graphically, I saw the following message when I choose encrypt option for boot partition,

[image]

Please suggest, how can I add encryption only for my boot partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't encrypt the `/boot` partition. This partition is what boots and decrypts the rest of the system.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. As you said, I should not encrypt the boot partition, now I understand that,but could I ask you that is it possible to do?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Some part must perform the decryption of the system so that you can start it, and that is located in `/boot`.

Comment: He didn't say you shouldn't.  He said you **can't**. GRUB doesn't speak encryption, so it has to have a plaintext file system on which to find the initial RAM image, to load into memory and continue booting.  This image is a compressed linux kernel, so it *does* speak encryption, and thus it can ask for passphrases and decrypt other file systems before further continuing with boot.  If you still have problems, please consider opening a new question telling us **what you're trying to achieve** rather than **how** you're trying to achieve it.